# jdbc data retreiving using multi threading

Tags: java, jdbc

I am using jdbc mysql. Let's assume there is a table in my db called Test. And there is a 700k rows. But fetching all rows are taking huge time. I am using preparedStatement. But I want to use multi threading in such a way that think there is 10 threads. for. eg 1st thread will fetch 70k rows then 2nd will fetch next 70k and so on. How to implement this?

Comment: Well, 700 000 db rows is a considerable amount. Even if the query is lightning fast, the transportation will take so much time that multithreading won't help you here. You need to ask yourself why you need to fetch 700 000 records at once. Certainly you can't display them all at once, they take some amount of memory too. What are you doing with the rows, i.e. what's your real problem?

Comment: It's not possible anyway. Per definition, a database is not required to provide rows in a deterministic way. So there are no 'first' 70k rows. And reusing the same `ResultSet` won't help, because the database will still work synchronously on it.

Comment: @Izruo Don't talk rubbish. One of the basic queries you can perform is by using `ORDER BY x LIMIT y OFFSET z` (or whatever the syntax is in your database). So you *could* do what he asked, but it wouldn't help in any way.

Comment: @Kayaman For that you need a criteria you can order by. I know it's *really* rare, but I'm just working on a situation where I got *totally* generic data and I have absolutely no clue what I'm processing.

Comment: @Kayaman What do you mean by "it wouldn't help", isn't what Scott is asking a crude version of map reduce?

Comment: @Izruo A surrogate primary key is never a bad idea, so it's really hard to come up with a realistic situation where you *couldn't* do an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Depending on the specific actions to be performed on each row, maybe using a "main" thread to fetch them and schedule for each a processing task on a multithreaded `Executor` could work.

Comment: @asettouf There is no reduce here (except maybe in his code). The problem here is that multithreading can help when you want to use plenty of CPU, but the retrieval of data from the DB doesn't depend on the CPU therefore making additional threads a moot point. Now since he didn't tell us what he intends to do with those rows, there's no way to give a good answer to this question. This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Kayaman Indeed you have a point here, I would assume he is going to get the CPU busy with those rows, but of course it remains an assumption so far. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if this is too obvious and you tried it or it won't work in your situation, but caching might be very helpful here.

Regarding actually doing it with multi-threading, It might make sense to have some procedure you run (might need a new column in your table to do this) that would assign ids that you can query - something like " WHERE id BETWEEN value1 AND value2".  Each Thread would query a different range.  This would be faster than using order by, since this way avoids the need for the database to sort.

If you do want to go the order by route though, consider indexing your database so that that ordering doesn't take extra time.